# WPF fix Grid position inside a Button

Tags: c#, wpf

A `Button` contains a `Grid`. The structure is like the follows:

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>

        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

The problem is that the `TextBlock`s position aren't fixed, so you can see the following situation, where the gridline is moved to the right when the text on left becomes longer. How to make the `TextBlock`s position fixed inside the grid cell (so the middle grid line stays regardless of the text length)?

[image]

---

EDIT: The above XAML will fix the positons of the TextBlocks as it is, but will not work when the `Grid` is inside a button. Images below of a Grid with blue background on a silver button: we can see the grid line changes as the text changes (while the ratio stays the same?) primarily because the Grid occupies different region of the Button.

So guess my real question is: How to make the `Grid` occupy the entire Button? (if the grid stays fixed, so does its grid line.)

[image]
[image]

---

EDIT2:
Below is the code that generates the Button, Grid, Viewbox, TextBlock structure represented by the above XAML. This code generates the `Button`s as shown below, where the green `Grid` does not stretch to the entire blue `Button` and its occupied area differs based on its content. Setting Grid's properties as `g.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    g.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;` doesn't work.

[image]

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Background = Brushes.DeepSkyBlue;

Grid g = new Grid();
g.Name = "grid";
g.ShowGridLines = true;
g.Background = Brushes.LimeGreen;
g.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
g.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

//create columns
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int len = i == 0 ? 3 : 1;
    ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd.Width = new GridLength(len, GridUnitType.Star);
    g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
}


//viewbox col 0
Viewbox vb = new Viewbox();
TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
vb.Child = tb1;
Grid.SetRow(vb, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(vb, 0);
g.Children.Add(vb);

//viewbox col 1
Viewbox vb2 = new Viewbox();
TextBlock updown = new TextBlock();
vb2.Child = updown;
//specify the Marlett Font
updown.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("updownBlock");
Grid.SetRow(vb2, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(vb2, 1);
g.Children.Add(vb2);

//add grid to button
b.Content = g;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

using this example, grid will allot the required space to right column first and then remaining space will be given to left column.

I also removed the row definition as 1 row with * height is the default for grid

---

**EDIT**

in order to distribute the space based weighted proportion of available space you may define the weight in star values to both of the columns

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

In above example grid will render left column 3 times bigger then the right column which will be rendered in 1/4 of the total space.

---

**EDIT**

set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` & `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the button so that the Grid can occupy whole space, by default it is Center.

Comment: thanks, this works. but now the right column becomes huge and left is tiny. How to specify the right column to take exactly 1/4 width of the grid regardless of the content of the left?

Comment: For exactly 1/4 width you can use that markup:
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Comment: isn't `<ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>` same as `<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>`? this seems to work with just the Grid, but doesn't work when the `Grid` is inside a `Button`. I'll update the question with more images.

Comment: @green, could you also post some sample code?, you may set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the button so that the grid occupy whole space.

Comment: @pushpraj I'ved tried `Stretch`, but no use. (isn't that the default option?) My buttons are generated in C#, but the latter 2 images are just `Grid` inside a `Button` in XAML. I'll edit the question to include that.

Comment: @green, Could you please share some code for button generation?

Comment: @pushpraj I just added the code, which produces the same thing as the XAML. I made the background color of the Grid different from that of the Button, so it's easy to see the problem.

Comment: @pushpraj sorry I misread your previous `HorizontalContentAlignment` as simply `HorizontalAlignment`, which did solve my problem eventually. Would you add it to your answer so I can accept it as the solution? thanks!

Comment: Try use Button.Template as advised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647009/how-to-get-button-content-to-fill-width-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `Grid`'s Alignment, setting the `Button`'s `ContentAlignment` finally did the trick

```
b = new Button();
b.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
b.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
```

Now the gridline stays regardless of length of the content :)

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I'm very glad to find your post.:) I've been trying to position image on the left side of a button for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your ColumnDefinition  width is 3 and *.  * indicates all of the available space, also your textbox or Grid'd width does not seems to be fixed hence it is but obvious that textbloxk's position will change.

Possible steps you can take:
1. Set ColumnDefinition  width="Auto"
2. Set the width of textblock and the parent Grid

Answer (score 0):

Buttonobject.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
Buttonobject.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

Stretch property will make the content aligned to the button's grid